the meaning of 'terms' in some context together with the word 'concrete'

It is easier to think in concrete terms rather than in the abstract.

(sorce: from my dictionary for the 'concrete' entry)
What's the meaning of the 'terms' here?

In some contexts, such as "Honey" is a term of endearment, Please explain in simple terms, a term means a word or expression. But In the cited example, terms is more like viewpoints, perspectives, ideas, concepts (such as might be expressed using words).

In concrete terms means in a manner that relies only on  ideas that are concrete. And concrete (vice abstract) means with specific real-world referents. For example, the sentence Generosity induces relational enhancements is much more abstract than You shared your cookies with Julia, which pleased her greatly, which is more concrete.
Here, terms doesn’t necessarily mean words or vocabulary.  Instead, it’s possible that it’s being used in much the same sense as in the expression in terms of, which can mean “regarding” or “with respect to.” As an example, consider Though not having much money, she is rich in terms of family and good friends. Without more context it’s impossible to say whether the author means literally “words.”

If so, then 'in the abstract' means "in the abstract terms", doesn't it? Or, 'the abstract' is a noun?

I think that (at least the way you have worded this last question) you offer a false choice. Yes, in the abstract could be replaced here with in abstract terms (no the). But the abstract is not a noun; it’s a noun phrase.

I found this sentence now('abstract' entry) "The research shows that pre-school children are capable of thinking in abstract terms.", and it's the same as your comment.

It is easier to think in concrete terms rather than in abstract ones, is a better sentence. That said, in the abstract=in abstract terms.

"Terms", in this context, means the vocabulary used to describe or explain something. Sometimes the word "terms" is prefixed to specify the vocabulary or language of a particular subject or field - for example, certain words may have meanings as "scientific terms" but mean something else in a non-scientific context.
We use the word "concrete" to mean fixed, immovable, clearly defined, or - as in the case of your example - tangible. "Concrete terms" Can sometimes mean an agreed set of words or phrases that would be widely understood, but in the case of your example, the precise meaning is clear by the contrast that it is the opposite of abstract. It is therefore urging the listener/reader to think literally or physically about something rather than intangibly, or in the abstract.

If it's vocabulary then I think it should remove 'the' in the "in the abastract".

@gomadeng no, "in the abstract" is a common phrase, with "abstract" being a noun.

I mean if the 'terms' in 'concrete terms' is vocabulary, then we don't need 'the' in "in the abstract" because there's no 'the' in "concrete terms'. My dictionary says 'the+abstract' could be 'an abstract idea'. Your mentioning "a common phrase" is the same as my dictionary says: an abastract idea?

@gomadeng "the abstract" is a different phrase from "concrete terms". They're not linked grammatically. "In the abstract" is an idiomatic phrase. You may have confused it with the phrase "in abstract ones". That phrase would not use "the".

@gomadeng right, "in the abstract" is a chunk that describes "to think", and grammatically has nothing to do with "terms".

@DanGetz The "in concrete terms" is contrasted with "in the abstract" and this is important in terms of getting the right meaning of 'terms'. This is like "concrete terms vs. the abstract(without the)". I think 'terms' is more of a concept/idea than vocabulary in my example sentence. And both phrase modifies 'to think': adverbial phrase. So, without 'the', namely 'in abstract terms' should be the counter part of 'concrete terms'. If not 'in the abstract' as a chunk(as you said as common;fixed), describes 'to think' with the meaning "in outline"

Thanks for your kind reminding me of the common expression of "in the abstract".
